# What exactly does "Speed" affect?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

Character customization allows for modifications to a character's attack, defense, and speed. Attack improves outgoing damage and knockback. Defense reduces incoming damage and knockback, improves shield strength, and increases the "perfect shield" timing window. So what exactly does speed affect? Please provide evidence.

Possible factors to consider:

- Dash speed
- Walking speed
- Air speed
- Fall speed
- Jump height
- Attack execution time
- Time between attacks
- Recovery time
- Directional influence
- Dash attack travel distance
- Dodge roll travel distance
- Smash attack charge time
- Dashing turn time

Comment: I've noticed that it affects movement speed and jump height, though other stats may be included in that.

Answer (score 2):

Raising speed will:

- Raise Dash speed
- Raise Walking speed
- Raise Air speed
- Raise Jump Height
- Raise dash turn time
- Lower Attack damage
- Lower Launch distance
- All others unaffected.

Raising defense will lower everything that speed will raise.
Raising attack will not affect speed, but will lower defense.
(It's hard to provide evidence, but you can just see for yourself.)

Comment: If raising defense lowers speed and raising attack lowers defense, then raising attack must raise speed.  Your answer is self-contradictory.

Comment: The speed stat doesn't lower attack damage or launch distance, but equipment that raises speed also lowers the attack stat. Is your answer based on your own observations or do you have a source you could link?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: No, it's like rock paper scissors. attack lowers defense, defense lowers speed, and speed lowers attack.

Comment: @Brian: It's my own observations, but believe me when I say that I've studied it _thoroughly_. I know for sure that raising the speed stat will lower attack damage.

Answer (score 1):

Equipment comes in various types, which each have three rarities. Higher rarities result in stronger stat modifications. If a piece of equipment has an extra effect, it does not show its rarity. The frequency rate of each type of equipment appears to be based on how many characters can utilize it - for example, Swords are much more common than Pikmin.

Speed equipment increases walking, dashing, air speed, jump height, and fast-falling speed. Reduces landing lag, but does not increase gravity, nor falling speed. Positive speed values will lower the fighter's weight limit for holding Smash Run powers, while negative speed values increase the weight limit.

There are a lot of equipment pieces, so if you want to take a look at them all, [I've included a link to the wiki.](http://www.ssbwiki.com/equipment)

Comment: This is a start, but only covers the more obvious parts of the question. Run speed, walk speed, air speed, and fall speed are affected, but what about jump height, attack execution time, time between attacks, recovery time, and directional influence? What about dash attack travel distance, dodge roll travel distance, and smash attack charge time? Is the time it takes to turn around while dashing affected?

Comment: I changed the question to display possible factors more clearly, and added those that I thought of in my previous comment. You have a good answer so far, but I'm looking for something much more detailed.

Comment: I did some testing, and jump height definitely is affected. I'm looking for an answer that has evidence to support its conclusions.

Comment: @Brian I would like to see what testing you have done. According to everything that I've experienced, jump height is not affected. Only the first three bullet points in your list are affected.

Comment: I don't remember which character I first tested with, but I think it was Greninja. I used the testing mode of custom character creation. With no equipment, the character was able to jump almost to the top of the screen, and with three speed boosting pieces of equipment (with no modifiers), the character could easily jump beyond the top of the screen. I then did the same test with Jigglypuff and saw similar results.

Comment: @Brian You are using equipment. Equipment has Brawn/Defense/Agility. Agility is not the same as a character's speed stat that is increased in a Smash Run. Plus, equipment can have secondary effects that are not displayed when selecting it. There's the difference you are experiencing.

Comment: This question is not about Smash Run power-ups. Brawn/Protection/Agility are prefixes for badges that affect Attack/Defense/Speed. Please reread my question.

Comment: You use the word speed. You may have meant agility when you first asked the question. Equipment affects agility. Smash run speed power ups affect the base speed of your character. I can provide what changes when equiping agility equipment in a bit.

Comment: The game uses the term "speed", so that's the term I used. The game only uses the word "agility" as a prefix for badges that affect speed.